Who wrote the third edition of Young's Literal Translation?
The third edition of Young's Literal Translation states that Robert Young wrote three editions : 1862, 1887 and 1898 and states on the cover '... he released the third and final edition, the 1898 edition'.
However inside, is stated (of the second, 1887) 'the work has been subjected to a fresh revision, making no alteration on the principles on which the Translation proceeds'.
These two statements cloud the fact that Robert Young departed this life in October 14th, 1888.
Thus it was others/another who subjected the 1887 (second edition) to a further revision and produced 'Young's Literal Translation Edition 3, 1898.'
I am interested to discover who (apparently anonymously) wrote this third edition and what exactly was their translation philosophy.

EDIT regarding the 'Publisher's Note' see Revised Edition.
The Publisher's Note mentions the introduction of the Revised Version of the Bible. But Robert Young only used the Received Text for his Literal Translation, not the Critical Text.
Am I to understand that the Third Edition of Young's Literal Translation, compiled after his decease, is a Literal Translation of the Critical Text/Westcott & Hort Text ?

The publishers released a revised 3rd edition as the earlier releases had been exhausted.
The preface of the 3rd edition reads:

Publishers' Note to the Third Edition
NOTWITHSTANDING the fact that the Revised Version of the Old and the New Testament has come into the field since the learned and lamented author first issued his Literal Translation of the Bible, the demand for it from year to year has continued remarkably steady. This indicates that it still fills a place of its own among helps to the earnest student of Holy Scripture. In 1887 Dr Young issued a Revised Edition, of which two impressions are exhausted. The work has been subjected to a fresh revision, making no alteration on the principles on which the Translation proceeds, but endeavouring to make it as nearly perfect in point of accuracy on its present lines as possible. The Publishers accordingly issue this new Revised Edition in the hope that earnest students of the Bible, by attaining to a clearer apprehension of the meaning of the inspired writer, may more clearly and fully apprehend the mind of the Spirit by whom all Holy Scripture has been given to us.
Edinburgh, January 1898.  Source: YLT

From Biblegateway.com:

The Bible text designated YLT is from the 1898 Young's Literal Translation by Robert Young who also compiled Young's Analytical Concordance. This is an extremely literal translation that attempts to preserve the tense and word usage as found in the original Greek and Hebrew writings. The text was scanned from a reprint of the 1898 edition as published by Baker Book House, Grand Rapids Michigan. The book is still in print and may be ordered from Baker Book House. Obvious errors in spelling or inconsistent spellings of the same word were corrected in the computer edition of the text.   Source:  Biblegateway


That was helpful, Gina. As long as the changes to the 3rd edition were only "obvious errors in spelling or inconsistent spellings of the same word in the computer edition of the text", fair enough.
